# Validation error with select input using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a form used to create clients, and in one of the fields I have to choose the language of the client. In the model I have a validation to check the field is not null, but the validation error is getting displayed even when a language is provided.

View:

```
<%= f.input :locale, as: :select, collection: locale_for_select, prompt: false %>
```

Model:

```
validates :locale, presence: true
```

Controller:

```
  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    if @client.save
      redirect_to @client, notice: t_notice('controllers.successfully_created', Client)
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
      redirect_to @client, notice: t_notice('controllers.successfully_updated', Client)
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end
```

I have used the browser's developer tools to check the value is actually being send, although the validation at the model fails.

Any idea about what's going on?

**EDIT**:

I have noticed this error only happens when creating a new client, not while editing an existing one. However, when I edit a client this new value is not being persisted to database

**EDIT 2**:

- Using rails 3.2.22
- Using ruby 2.1.6

**EDIT 3**:

This is strange because in the same form I have some other select inputs that are working properly, and which are treated in a similar way.

Comment: Is it allowed via `strong_parameters` in the controller?

Comment: We are not using strong_parameters, although this field is included in attr_accesible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had added a localized field using Globalize, and I did not take [this](https://github.com/globalize/globalize#gotchas) into account:

> Because globalize uses the :locale key to specify the locale during
>   mass-assignment, you should avoid having a locale attribute on the
>   parent model.

What I did to solve this issue is renaming my `:locale` attribute to `:client-locale` and execute the corresponding migration to rename the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @client = Client.new(params[:client])
  if @client.save
    redirect_to @client, notice: t_notice('controllers.successfully_created', Client)
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end


def update
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
    redirect_to @client, notice: t_notice('controllers.successfully_updated', Client)
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Comment: I've added the methods involved ;)

Comment: This is not all my code, but I cannot post the whole controller due to company privacy... What I cannot understand is that one of the fields is working properly, and a similar one is never getting saved

Comment: I updated, and you should check where is `@client` from?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean with this last comment

Comment: you should find @client variable first, compare with my code

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and comment back